# dask: dtype mismatch in read_json when convert-string=False

Tags: python, dask

When reading a JSON-lines file that contains complex fields with dask I am unable to get the correct data types.

The JSON-lines file looks like this

```json
{"col1": "some text", "col2": ["a", "b", "c"]}
```

I set `dataframe.convert-string` to `False` to make dask read the second column as a list of strings (see [this comment](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/10139#issuecomment-1655928619)).  However, this gives me the data type `object` for both columns.  If I provide explicit data types (as suggested in the above link) it fails with a metadata mismatch error.  How do I set the data types correctly to string for strings and object for complex columns?  Or is it fine for both columns to be of type object?

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import config

df = dd.read_json('df.jsonl', orient='records', lines=True)
df.dtypes
# col1    string[pyarrow]
# col2    string[pyarrow]    ## WRONG!
# dtype: object

config.set({'dataframe.convert-string': False})

df = dd.read_json('df.jsonl', orient='records', lines=True)
df.dtypes
# col1    object
# col2    object
# dtype: object

df = dd.read_json('df.jsonl', orient='records', lines=True,
                  metadata={'col1': 'string[pyarrow]',
                            'col2': 'object'})
df.dtypes
# col1    string[pyarrow]
# col2             object
# dtype: object

df.head()
# ValueError: Metadata mismatch found in `from_delayed`.
```

Comment: Which column gives the mismatch in the last line?

Comment: @mdurant col1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is it fine for both columns to be of type object?

The short answer is "yes". Before the arrow types, object used to be used for string and also any other python types like your lists.

When you set dataframe.convert-string=False, pure string columns will become type `object`. The purpose of `meta=` isn't "I would like these types" but rather "these are the types I expect" - so when you get an `object` out but say you expect `string[pyarrow]`, you get your exception.

For most purposes, keeping strings as objects will be fine, especially since there's no vectorised path to reading them from JSON (with pandas, anyway). Also, you are already handling a lot of string objects in your lists, so the memory improvement may not be significant.

Comment: So "advisable" in [the referenced link](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/10139#issuecomment-1655928619) means "could save memory"?  And this is unlikely in my case?

Comment: I believe so, but nothing is as good as concrete measured data